# How to change the default T4 Template for Entity Framework 6 (EF6)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, t4

I've installed the latest [EFTools for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40762). I find the T4 template it ships with that to generate both the Context (Context.tt) and Entities (.tt) is lacking in functionality. I'd like to create a new one and use it as a default for all new models i create (so i don't have to manually overwrite the defaults for every model. This becomes even more annoying across multiple developers on our team).

Some obvious omissions to the default just to give you a taste for what i'm looking for

1. No constructor for DbContext that takes in a DbConnection (strange that this is missing even though they advertise it quite a bit)
2. No Factory Method for entities that takes in only non-nullable
   fields.
3. Others..

My main questions then is, assuming i have a t4 template that i like, how to set my own T4 template as the default for all newly created models. I'm using EF 6.1.3

Comment: The following post described how to override the T4 templates: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/06/mvcscaffolding-overriding-the-t4-templates/

Comment: Have a look at the EF Reverse POCO Template https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838

Comment: [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg251242.aspx) is the MSDN area for writing t4.  I would like something to map Table Valued Functions to a matching Table entity so I can query temporal tables in linq.